# Sharing link with fragment identifier to Twitter

Tags: twitter, share, fragment-identifier

Using the Twitter share button, I can't seem to pass links that has fragment identifiers. The links turn up with only the base path of the site (e.g. "http://mysite.com/").
I've been reading through the previous threads posted here about Twitter and sharing but I can't seem to get my head around if Twitter allows it, if there's a special parse method to be used etc.

I've tried both parsing a regular URL (http://mysite.com/#example) and a decoded version (http://mysite.com/%23example), none of which are working. Would appreciate any help or direction on this subject.

Comment: did you find an acceptable answer yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [URL Shortening service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening#Notable_URL_Shortening_Services).

A service that handles fragment identifiers, like TinyURL, can solve this for you. For example, "http://example.com/#example" becomes "http://tinyurl.com/85rtaym", and works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter automatically removes # from links, I had the same problem. To solve this I used the following code:

`<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=xxx&url=<?php echo esc_url ( get_permalink()); ?><?php echo "%23example"; ?>" target="_blank">`

This part: `<?php echo esc_url ( get_permalink()); ?>` is only relevant to WordPress but you can replace this with your URL.